# Difference between cloud computing and regular hosting

Tags: web-applications, cloud

I am looking at a number of web application to SMS notification services. Some of them say they operate from a cloud, others say they are hosted in country.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Some countries have laws in regards to where the data must be stored. It doesn't necessary mean that application running in given country is not "in the cloud", it only means that all hosts that serve that application must physically be located in a given country.
This is so call data residency policy.